# how to use @Import and @ComponentScan in SpringMvcCOnfig

Tags: java

`now，I'm trying to import SpringMvcSupport extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport into @Configuration

```
@ComponentScan({"com.itheima.controller"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringMvcConfig {
}
there are two plans，but one worked，I want  to know the resaon
First one:
`@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.itheima.controller","com.itheima.config"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringMvcConfig {
}`

`@Configuration
`public class SpringMvcSupport extends WebMvcConf

urationSupport {
    //设置静态资源访问过滤，当前类需要设置为配置类，并被扫描加载
    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        //当访问/pages/????时候，从/pages目录下查找内容
        registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").addResourceLocations("/pages/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/plugins/**").addResourceLocations("/plugins/");
    }
}``
```

It is working;

The Second:

```
`    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan({"com.itheima.controller"})
    @EnableWebMvc
    @Import(SpringMvcSupport.class)
    public class SpringMvcConfig {
    }`
`public class SpringMvcSupport extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    //设置静态资源访问过滤，当前类需要设置为配置类，并被扫描加载
    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        //当访问/pages/????时候，从/pages目录下查找内容
        registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").addResourceLocations("/pages/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/plugins/**").addResourceLocations("/plugins/");
    }
}`
```

the error is NO mapping for ***.html

i want to know why,I am a new one here`